# Store an Array list using cookies JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Is it possible for me to store an array list in a cookie?

**My array list would be something like this**

itemsarray

```js
        var productId=[];
      productId['id'] = 'product id';
      productId['title'] = 'product-name';
        
        itemsarray.push(productId);
```

```
0: [id: 153359796766, title: "adidas EQT Cushion ADV Shoes Men's "]
1: [id: 391912235126, title: "Sonos One Voice-Controlled Wireless Smart"]
```

I have tried the following method but no luck it always returns me a blank array. I think the issue is in `JSON.stringify`

```js
json_str = JSON.stringify(itemsarray);
$.cookie('ID', json_str);
console.log(json_str);
```

is there any solution?

Comment: `$.cookie` is not a valid js.Try [document.cookie](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or try with [local storage](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwj-uK6kp8_gAhUKQI8KHagHAlEQFggEMAA&client=internal-uds-cse&cx=012971019331610648934:m2tou3_miwy&usg=AOvVaw3nbUThK3YF9Kpvv3Z-kxfH)

Comment: to be able to use `$.cookie` you must have the jQuery Cookie Plugin (at least  that I know, it's no longer maintened)

Comment: @prasanth : sorry it was my bad I'm using jQuery and not javascript.

Comment: jQuery IS javascript

Comment: if you log `json_str ` right after using JSON.stringify, what it logs?

Comment: You can do it by using localStorage.setItem('ID', json_str);

Comment: @CalvinNunes  :it shows something like this ->>>  []

Comment: Can you show us exactly the structure of `itemsarray`?  Because the way you are showing up there, it's not a valid array, it's an object

Comment: @CalvinNunes I'm generating this array when user clicks on a link. i have changed the code . please have a look.it works inside a loop

Comment: Yeah, but you are using it wrong. You don't want an array, you want an object... `itemsarray` is always empty because it is pushing empty values, you can't use  bracket notation with keys that are not integer to insert values in an array. It must be `productId = {}` (object, not array)

Comment: @CalvinNunes: could you please show me how it's done

Comment: just change `productId = []` to `productId = {}` (and don't forget to initialize `itemsarray`, something like `itemsarray = []`

Comment: @CalvinNunes :  okay let me check that and get back to you

Comment: @CalvinNunes: LOL. it works !! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

First of al, your array should include json.

For example:

```js
const items = [
    {id: 153359796766, title: "adidas EQT Cushion ADV Shoes Men's "},
    {id: 391912235126, title: "Sonos One Voice-Controlled Wireless Smart"}
];
```

If you don't need that data serverside, you can use localStorage:

```js
localStorage.setItem('items', items);
```

Comment: localStorage didn't store objects like `items` you show here. `localStorage` only stores strings, nothing more, that's why the use of `JSON.stringify`, that transforms objects to strings.

Comment: Yes you'r right. I forgot to add it :) so it is localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));

Answer (score 0):

You could do that also wiht localStorage ususaly most browsers alow you to store more data(max 5Mb in 2019)in localstorage, and it is also better for the performance if you dont need the server to read those.

```
window.localStorage.array_1 = JSON.stringify(itemsarray);
console.log(window.localStorage.array_1);

/// and to convert it back to an array object
console.log(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.array_1));
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the solutions are providing an alternative and suggesting him to use local storage instead, which is a nice suggestion (personally I've never had to use cookies instead of the storage) but in case OP def needs to use cookies this would be a vanilla approach to the problem:

You can simply store that array by doing:

```
document.cookies = `id={$JSON.stringify(itemsArray)}`
```

That will store your values in the cookies string. Accessing the value is a bit more 'complicated' because cookies are stored as a string separated by semicolons:

```
cookies = 'value=thevalue;value2=the2value'
```

What you'll need to do is either split the string by ";" or running a regexp as suggested by the mdn site:

var cookieValue = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)**id**\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");

where **id** stands for your cookie key.

Then you just do a `JSON.parse(cookieValue)`

Source: [Small cookie framework by mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie#A_little_framework_a_complete_cookies_readerwriter_with_full_unicode_support)